# To fix for both doughnut for chrome and firefox

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image: dougnut chart]

I want this doughnut chart to be fixed for both chrome and firefox anyone can help 
I have put style="margin-top:-60px;"
I am getting correct alignment in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: Show us your code, bro.

Comment: @amedina Just now I updated it can you check it the full code is                           <canvas id="gtwhlt_doughnut" style="height:28vh;width:28vh;margin-top:-60px;"></canvas>